# Apache FTP server is not seeing a logging jar package that exists in the class path

Tags: apache, ftp, glassfish, slf4j

I'm using Apache's FTP server.  The FTP server is loaded through a singleton bean in Glassfish.  I was previously able to run the FTP server when I was using a PropertiesUserManager, but I wanted to tie in some JPA logic, so I wrote a custom class class that implement's the UserManager interface.  However, I'm facing a class loading issue.  The slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar file and the slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar file exists in glassfish's lib folder and I have restarted glassfish.

Here's the stack trace:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton LibertyFTPServer
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:449)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton LibertyFTPServer
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:545)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:717)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:117)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:965)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:394)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:377)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:536)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpServerContext.<init>(DefaultFtpServerContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory.<init>(FtpServerFactory.java:51)
    at regina.eis.filemonitor.ejb.LibertyFTPServer.applicationStartup(LibertyFTPServer.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1010)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:113)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder not found by slf4j.api [95]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 95 more
```

And here's the singleton bean

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class LibertyFTPServer {
private FtpServer ftpServer;
@Resource(name="connectionFactory", mappedName="connectionFactory")
private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
@Resource(name="ftpSessionQueue", mappedName="ftpSessionQueue")
private Queue ftpSessionQueue;
@Resource(name="accountValidatorQueue", mappedName="accountValidatorQueue")
private Queue accountValidatorQueue;
@Resource(name="userManagerQueue", mappedName="userManagerQueue")
private Queue userManagerQueue;
@EJB
private DoctypeLookupDAO doctypeLookupDAO;

public static final String REMOTE_SERVER_ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0";
public static final String USER_PROPERTIES = "C:/user.properties";
private static Logger LOGGER = 
    Logger.getLogger(LibertyFTPServer.class.getName());

@PostConstruct
public void applicationStartup() {
    LOGGER.info("The application is starting");


    final Ftplet ftplet = new ImageConversionFtplet(connectionFactory, ftpSessionQueue);

    final ConnectionConfigFactory connectionConfigFactory = new ConnectionConfigFactory();
    connectionConfigFactory.setAnonymousLoginEnabled(false);


    final FtpServerFactory ftpServerFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
    ftpServerFactory.setConnectionConfig(connectionConfigFactory.createConnectionConfig());

    final ListenerFactory listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();



    final UserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new UserManagerFactory() {
        @Override
        public UserManager createUserManager() {
            LOGGER.finer("Creating a user manager");
            return new EJBUserManager(connectionFactory, accountValidatorQueue, userManagerQueue);
        }
    };



    listenerFactory.setServerAddress(REMOTE_SERVER_ADDRESS);
    listenerFactory.setIdleTimeout(20);

    // iterates through the list of port numbers and adds the same listener to
    // each document type
    listenerFactory.setPort(21);
    ftpServerFactory.addListener("default", listenerFactory.createListener());

    ftpServerFactory.setUserManager(userManagerFactory.createUserManager());

    final Map<String, Ftplet> ftpletMap = new HashMap<String, Ftplet>();

    ftpletMap.put("default", ftplet);

    ftpServerFactory.setFtplets(ftpletMap);
    ftpServer = ftpServerFactory.createServer();
    try {
        ftpServer.start();
    } catch (FtpException ex) {

    }
}


    @PreDestroy
    public void applicationShutdown() {
        ftpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get proper class loading by changing the sun-web.xml's class-loader tag's delegate attribute from true to false.

`<class-loader delegate="false">`; is what I have now in sun-web.xml.