# ClassNotFound exception using Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, glassfish-3, jackson

I have a Spring 3 MVC app that I am setting up some ajax actions for.
My controller action looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody Plan addPlan(@RequestBody Plan plan, Principal principal) {
     //Save the plan
}
```

When I post the Plan data from my browser the app throws a ClassNotFound exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant not found by jackson-mapper-asl [176]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

The Plan object itself does not contain any joda-date types. Though it contains a collection of objects that do.  Originally I was pulling in the joda-date jar via my DOA jar but the error persists even if I add a direct dependency to my web project's pom.xml.  I'm using the joda classes elsewhere in this project without any issue.

**Additional information**
Here are the relevant dependencies from my web pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post relevant portion of your POM? One thing you can always do to verify is unzip your WAR and make sure the Joda jar is in the WEB-INF lib folder

Comment: Are you deploying your webapp into an OSGi server?

Comment: @Perception I added a chunk of my pom above.  I have verified that the joda-time jar is in my war file.

Comment: @Luciano I'm deploying onto a local glassfish server from within netbenas.

Comment: Oh, I'm not familiar with Glassfish but it looks like it uses OSGi / Felix. Are there any Glassfish services that you are using, or is your Spring app self-contained? (For instance, if your datasources are defined in Glassfish, or they are Spring beans of your app). What I was thinking is if you can try deploying your application on a simpler server like Tomcat, and see if the error still happens.

Comment: Your POM looks good as confirmed by locating the JAR in your WAR file. Based off what you have posted you shouldn't be getting that error but I'll think about this some more on the way to work.

Comment: I get my datasource from glassfish via jndi, but that's the only server dependency I have.  I'll see what it will take to get this deployed on something else later today.

Comment: Please paste output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I think, `jackson-mapper-asl.pom` should list JODA as optional dependency, as we don't know which Joda library version was used to compile Jackson. Looks like a minor bug for Jackson team.

Comment: As @Luciano mentioned, I bet it is an OSGI /Felix class loading issue.

Comment: For what it is worth, Jackson does declare Joda packages for OSGi as "Dynamic-Import", to avoid hard depdendency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow came across this question: [Apache FTP server is not seeing a logging jar package that exists in the class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422289/apache-ftp-server-is-not-seeing-a-logging-jar-package-that-exists-in-the-class-p)

Their solution of setting `<class-loader delegate="false">` in glassfish-web.xml seems to have fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this on Glassfish JIRA https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20808